# What extra codecs do I need to play movies from Google Play?

Tags: codec, videos

Mint is the only Linux distribution (distro) I've found that lets me play movies I've purchased on Google Play without installing anything extra. What does Mint have in its multimedia pack that other distros don't and is there a way to get them added to elementary OS?

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot of what you see on Chrome when you attempt to play a movie?

Comment: What browser are you using and what's the error message you get? I'm using Firefox and I have no problems to access my purchased movies at Google Play.

Comment: Rafael, are you running stock Elementary OS? if not, What have you added to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are attempting to play the video DRM protected video content in your browser, then according to the Google Play help, you will require Adobe Flash player. See: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2844198?hl=en. The system requirements note that Ubuntu and Linux OS users (so including elementary OS) must install the HAL module. A third party PPA provides the necessary module (see http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10). Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: I guess, this will be the solution... at least, if Michael is using Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Either you can find out what codec(s) those file actually use (there should be a feature in your video player that will tell you), or you can try and add [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media), which has the latest VLC player and, among other things, the decoder necessary to watch H.265-encoded videos.